# Measuring function execution time and time of completion by default in R

Tags: r, time

Measuring function execution time in R is simple but pollutes the code.

```
t0 <- Sys.time()
my_function()
t1 <- Sys.time()
t1-t0
```

Is there some package or setting in R that makes it record the execution time (duration) and the time of completion and print that to the screen after the function output?

In stata this can be done by the setting:

```
set rmsg on
```

After that if you run a block of code, with the following 4 commands:

```
clear
set obs 3
gen x=1
```

The output window would display:

```
. clear
r; t=0.00 9:10:28

. set obs 3
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 3
r; t=0.00 9:10:28

. gen x=1
r; t=0.00 9:10:28

. 
end of do-file

r; t=0.00 9:10:28
```

Above we have execution and completion time for:

- each command command. This follow the commands own output (bare in mind `clear` and `gen` have no screen output).
- the hole command block. This is indicated by adding `end of do-file` and the time information after than.

I find this very useful when working on large datasets.

Is there a way to do this in R?

If not, would it be too complicated to create a package to implement this feature?

Comment: Are you using RStudio? Then, have a look at the [preview version](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/), which includes an easy profiling option that - I think - does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `microbenchmark` package. E.g.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(my_fun(), times = 100L, unit = "ms")
summary(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(my_fun(), times = 100L, unit = "ms"))$uq
```

With the latter option you can access entries for further tests.

Running example:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(factorial(100), times = 100L, unit = "us")
```